# How to preprocess MACRO and use value in the constant definition?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

In Delphi, I want to define the constants as follows:

```
const
  LANG_BUL = MAKELANGID(LANG_BULGARIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT);
```

But will get

```
[dcc32 Error] Utils.pas(15): E2026 Constant expression expected
```

How can let the compiler preprocess the macro and generate the constants before the compile starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Delphi there are no macros. `MAKELANGID` is a function - see unit `Winapi.Windows`. As such it can't be used to define a constant. You can manually "expand" `MAKELANGID` as a workaround:

```
const
  LANG_BUL =  WORD(SUBLANG_DEFAULT shl 10) or LANG_BULGARIAN;
```